# Moving divs over other divs with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a div to move to the bottom of the page without moving the divs i have under it.  I just want it to move down without interrupting the rest of the page.

This is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#MoveMe').click( function() { 
        $('#MoveMe').animate({
            marginTop: "+=1000px"
        }, 1500 );
    });
});
```

this is my css:

```
#MoveMe {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px, 30px;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#NoMove {
    z-index: 2;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

Header {
    position: absolute;
}
```

this is the body of my html:

```
<body>

    <Header>
        <div id = "MoveMe"> 
            <p> Hello </p>
        </div>

        <div id = "NoMove">
            hi
        </div>
    </Header>

    <script src= "jquery.js" ></script>
    <script src= "jqueryPage.js" ></script>

</body
```

Comment: You're going to have to use `position: absolute;`

Comment: Use: `#MoveMe {
position: absolute;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `position: absolute;` on the `#MoveMe` element.

Comment: The position absolute is the way to go. But I would also add you should also look at using a keyframe animation instead of using JavaScript intervals to perform an animation. Check out these pre-canned animations for a good reference http://daneden.me/animate